# How to load a sticker into WhatsApp from a website using a smartphone

Tags: web, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

My website contains WhatsApp stickers which users can download. I'm looking for an efficient solution for smartphone users to download these images/stickers instantly into WhatsApp from my website. Currently the only solution available seems to redirect users through third party apps that use WhatsApp API. These third party apps let users create their own custom stickerpack which they can then load into WhatsApp. I don't want to redirect my users through third party applications, I want them to be able to instantly add the sticker from my webpage.

So in a typical use-case:

1. A smartphone user selects a sticker to download on the website.
2. The smartphone user gets redirected to Whatsapp App to add the sticker.

I tried to look at the code of some third party apps that can create custom sticker packs. Specifically I looked at the link on the button that redirects users to the WhatsApp sticker menu. But can't find my way through swift code. Hopefully someone can help me out, since I'm not sure this is even possible and I am wasting my time for a small feature.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an app in IOS/Android to download the sticker from your site and call the Intents that WhatsApp provides you to add a sticker. They don't have a URI for adding stickers.

Check out https://github.com/whatsapp/stickers for more information